# C++ find whitespaces in substring

Tags: c++, string, substr

I want to know how can I find empty or whitespaces within substring in C++. For example:

```
string str = "( )"; // or str = "()"
```

Here, I want to make sure there is always something in between parenthesis. Function isspace() takes only one character so I have to search in loop. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) maybe?

Comment: You can write the function recursively. But there's no point trying to avoid a loop. Loops are for this situation, go from '(' to ')' counting whitespace (and consider what happens if there is no ')' or you hit another '('.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks for prompt reply. Yes I can use regex. I just want to know whether there is anything to check for empty or whitespace substring. I think you are right Malcolm. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::string::find()` to find the `(` and `)` characters, then use `std::string::find_first_not_of()` to check for any non-whitespace characters between those indexes.

```
string str = "( )"; // or str = "()"
string::size_type idx1 = str.find("(");
if (idx1 != string::npos) {
    ++idx1;
    string::size_type idx2 = str.find(")", idx1);
    if (idx2 != string::npos) {
        string tmp = str.substr(idx, idx2-idx1);
        string::size_type idx3 = tmp.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
        if (idx3 != string::npos) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. will try this solution.